# Using txt files (large lists containing strings) to search for anagrams

Tags: php, arrays, loops, char, embed

I am creating a program which checks whether seemingly random letters are in fact anagrams of coherent words.

I am using a .txt file from a URL which contains a list of the most commonly used words of the German language which I convert into the array `$dictionary` in which every element is equivalent to one word.

```
$dictionary = file('https://bwinf.de/fileadmin/user_upload/BwInf/2018/37/1._Runde/Material/woerterliste.txt');
```

I then convert the string which is typed into a field into individual words in an array by using `explode()`:

```
$str = $_POST["str"]; //name of the text field for the string
$words = explode(" ", $str);
```

I then define the function `is_anagram($a, $b)` which should check for anagrams and echo `$b` in case their characters match:

```
 function is_anagram($a, $b) {
        if (count_chars($a, 1) == count_chars($b, 1)) {
            echo $b . " ";
        }
    }
```

For comparing the elements of both arrays I create a `foreach` loop where I use the function mentioned above:

```
 foreach ($words as $word) {
        foreach ($dictionary as $dic) {
              is_anagram($word, $dic);
              }
        }
```

The loop should echo some of the strings that can be found in `$dictionary`, if the string written by the user features some anagrams.

However, when I submit a few words I know are congruent anagrams, the program does not echo anything.

Even more strangely, when I define `$dictionary` as a simple array instead using the .txt file, like

```
$dictionary = ["ahoi", "afer", "afferent"];
```

the function works as it is intended to do.

I'm quite sure there is some fault in `$dictionary`, maybe because the .txt file is very large. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you look at your PHP Error Log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dictionary = file('https://bwinf.de/fileadmin/user_upload/BwInf/2018/37/1._Runde/Material/woerterliste.txt');
```

$dictionary is a string, not an array in your example.

```
$tmpfile = file_get_contents('https://bwinf.de/fileadmin/user_upload/BwInf/2018/37/1._Runde/Material/woerterliste.txt');
$dictionary=explode("\n",$tmpfile);
```